# Looking for a jQuery function similar to wrapAll that will only wrap consecutive elements

Tags: jquery, wrapall

Is there a version of wrapAll that will only wrap consecutive elements? So this:

```
<p>foo</p>
<p>foo</p>
<h2>bar</h2>
<p>foo</p>
```

turns into this:

```
<div>
    <p>foo</p>
    <p>foo</p>
</div>
<h2>bar</h2>
<div>
    <p>foo</p>
</div>
```

When this is run?

```
$('p').wrapAll2('<div />')
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
$(function(){
    var cWrap=$('<div />');
    $('p').each(function(){
        var o = $(this).next('p').length;
        $(this).replaceWith(cWrap).appendTo(cWrap);
        if (!o) cWrap=$('<div />');
    });
});
```

or as a fully fledged plugin:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.wrapAll2 = function(wrapper){
        if (!this.length) return this;
        var cWrap=$(wrapper),
            tag = this.get(0).nodeName.toLowerCase();
        return this.each(function(){
            var o = $(this).next(tag).length;
            $(this).replaceWith(cWrap).appendTo(cWrap);
            if (!o) cWrap = $(wrapper);
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
$(function(){
    $('p').wrapAll2('<div />');
});
```

*Note that it presumes you will call it on homogeneous collections (as least all the same node type)

### EDIT

Experimentally, I've looked into jQuery's innards and found that it stores the selector used to create a collection! [at least on instantiation], so with that in mind I've created another version that at least works with the current version of jQuery, and **accepts any selector**!

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.wrapAll2 = function(wrapper) {
        if (!this.length) return this;
        var wrap = $(wrapper),
            sel = this.selector || this.get(0).nodeName.toLowerCase();
        return this.each(function() {
            var more = $(this).next(sel).length;
            console.log(this,more);
            $(this).replaceWith(wrap).appendTo(wrap);
            if (!more) wrap = $(wrapper);
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
$(function() {
    $('p, span').wrapAll2('<div />');
});
```

It does **not** work with things like this though: `$('p').add('span').wrapAll2('<div />');`

Answer (score 3):

I expounded on Shad's excellent answer and created some code that would take any selector, not just node types:

```
(function($){
    $.wrapAll2 = function(sel, wrapSel) {
        var wrap = $(wrapSel);
        $(sel).each(function() {
            var more = $(this).next(sel).length;
            $(this).replaceWith(wrap).appendTo(wrap);
            if (!more) wrap = $(wrapSel);
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
$(function() {
    $.wrapAll2('p', '<div/>');
});
```

Wish it could be passed a JQuery object instead of a selector string, but this works well enough for my purposes now.

Comment: Thanks =), with that consideration in mind, I've added another version.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a generic solution that works for **any jQuery selector**, and **also works when the collection has been modified**, such as using `add()` or `andSelf()` or `not()`:

### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wujX6/

```
(function($){
  $.fn.wrapConsecutive = function(wrapper){
    if (!this.length) return this;
    var thisRun,prev;
    this.each(function(){
      if (!prev || $(this).prev()[0]!=prev){
        if (thisRun) thisRun.wrapAll(wrapper);
        thisRun = $();
      }
      thisRun = thisRun.add(this);
      prev = this;
    });
    if (thisRun) thisRun.wrapAll(wrapper);
    return this;
  };
})(jQuery);
```

<sup>*Demo showing it working based on manipulated collections: http://jsfiddle.net/wujX6/1/*</sup>

---

The only caveat is that intervening Text nodes between consecutive elements are not included in the wrapping. So, for example, calling `$('p').wrapConsecutive('<div/>')` on 
this HTML:

```html
<p>foo</p>
<p>bar</b>
jim
<p>baz</p>
jar
```

… will result in this output:

```html
<div><p>foo</p><p>bar</b><p>baz</p></div>
jim
jar
```