# jQuery, wrap all consecutive elements?

Tags: jquery

With jQuery, is there a version of wrapAll that will wrap all consecutive elements? Like this:

```
<h2>bar</h2>
<h2>bar</h2>
<p>foo</p>
<p>foo</p>
<h2>bar</h2>
<p>foo</p>
<h2>bar</h2>
```

turns into this:

```
<h2>bar</h2>
<h2>bar</h2>
<div>
    <p>foo</p>
    <p>foo</p>
    <h2>bar</h2>
    <p>foo</p>
</div>
<h2>bar</h2>
```

---

Or even more complicated, with nested

:

```
<h2>bar</h2>
<h2>bar</h2>
<span>
    <p>foo</p>
    <p>foo</p>
</span>
<h2>bar</h2>
<p>foo</p>
<h2>bar</h2>
<span>
    <p>foo</p>
</span>
<h2>bar</h2>
```

turns into this:

```
<h2>bar</h2>
<h2>bar</h2>
<div>
    <span>
       <p>foo</p>
       <p>foo</p>
    </span>
    <h2>bar</h2>
    <p>foo</p>
    <h2>bar</h2>
    <span>
        <p>foo</p>
    </span>
</div>
<h2>bar</h2>
```

When this is run?

```
$('p').wrapAll2('<div />')
```

Comment: Using wrapAll will move the elements next to each other which changes the layout.  I want a way to wrap elements and any siblings that are between them.  Has anyone had this issue before?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Looking for a jQuery function similar to wrapAll that will only wrap consecutive elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8178396/looking-for-a-jquery-function-similar-to-wrapall-that-will-only-wrap-consecutive)

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know there's no such function, but you could write it yourself. On the first glance doesn't seem to be too difficult.

You'd have to go through all 'p' (or whatever you wan to wrap) elements on the page, find first one and then it's last parent then last one and it's last parent, then take all elements between, including first and last parents and wrap them into desired tag.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I wasn't clear in the post but it's a little more complicated because I would like it to find all nested elements not just one level down.